# mysql add constraint (ALTER) how to put them in order

Tags: mysql

I am trying to make sure when I mysqldump the database that the constraint are in numeric order after doing the below query. When I do a dump without AFTER (which doesn't work) it shows phppos_sales_ibfk_3 as the first constraint.

```
ALTER TABLE `phppos_sales`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `phppos_sales_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`location_id`) REFERENCES `phppos_locations` (`location_id`);    
  ADD CONSTRAINT `phppos_sales_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`employee_id`) REFERENCES `phppos_employees` (`person_id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `phppos_sales_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`) REFERENCES `phppos_customers` (`person_id`),
```

Code I am trying to do to alter `phppos_sales`

```
ALTER TABLE `phppos_sales`
   ADD CONSTRAINT `phppos_sales_ibfk_3` AFTER `phppos_sales_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`location_id`) REFERENCES `phppos_locations` (`location_id`);
```

I get an error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AFTER `phppos_sales_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`location_id`) REFERENCES `phppos_locat' at line 6
```

Comment: *Why* does the order in which the constraints are defined matter to you?

Comment: It is just to keep things organized when I export the database. I know it doesn't matter too much (if at all), but I was curious

Comment: I suspect you'll have to swallow your OCD on this one :)

Comment: Lol that made me laugh. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The "ADD CONSTRAINT" part of "ALTER TABLE" doesn't allow the keyword "AFTER".

You can control where columns appear in the table, but you can't control where constraints appear.